# Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/clearConsole'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetched this kind of error in my react project  **Can not find module 'react-dev-utils/clearConsole'** . React version of my project is 16.2.  Actually when I install prop-types with npm then I fetched this error and my project was stopped. I can not run my project again. What is the solution for this?

Comment: For this and similar error its a always a better idea to remove the node_modules folder and do npm install.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you lack some dependencies. In this particular example it is [react-dev-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils).

Simple `npm install --save-dev react-dev-utils` should do.